# Show that $z^5-1=(z-1)(z^2+2z\cos{\pi \over 5}+1)(z^2-2z\cos{2\pi \over 5}+1)$

Tags: complex-numbers

Show that

$ \quad \quad z^5-1=(z-1)(z^2+2z\cos{\dfrac{\pi}{5}}+1)(z^2-2z\cos{\dfrac{2\pi}{5}}+1)$

and deduce from this the closed formulas for $\cos{\dfrac{\pi}{5}}$ and $\cos{\dfrac{2\pi}{5}}$.

---

Here's what I did:

I assumed that it was correct, and using the fact that $z^5-1=(z-1)(z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1)$, I said that:

$ \quad z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1=(z^2+2z\cos{\dfrac{\pi}{5}}+1)(z^2-2z\cos{\dfrac{2\pi}{5}}+1)$

Letting $a=\cos{\dfrac{\pi}{5}}$ and $b=\cos{\dfrac{2\pi}{5}}$

$
\quad z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1=z^4+(2a-2b)z^3+(2-4ab)z^2+(2a-2b)z+1$

Equating the coefficients:

$\quad a-b= {1 \over 2} \quad$ and $ \quad ab={1 \over 4}$

Simultaneously solving, and knowing that $0<a<1$ and $0<b<1$:

$\cos{\dfrac{\pi}{5}}=\dfrac{1}{4} + \dfrac{\sqrt{5}}{4} \quad$ and $\quad \cos{\dfrac{2\pi}{5}}=-\dfrac{1}{4} + \dfrac{\sqrt{5}}{4}$

Then I said that, if I can prove the cosine formulas above in a different way, I have indirectly shown that the relationship shown in the question was true.

So, since $\cos{\pi}= \cos{(5 × (\frac{\pi}{5}))} =-1$ and with a little trig indentity,

$\quad 16{\cos^5{\pi \over 5}}-20{\cos^3{\pi \over 5}}+5{\cos{\pi \over 5}}+1=0$

With substitution $x=\cos{\pi \over 5}$:

$16x^5-20x^3+5x+1=0$, a polynomial that has roots at $x=-1$, $x= \frac{1}{4} - \frac{\sqrt{5}}{4}$, and $x=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{4}$.

The only possible solution is $\cos{\pi \over 5}=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{4}$, and the double angle formula shows that $ \cos{\frac{2\pi}{5}}=-\frac{1}{4} + \frac{\sqrt{5}}{4}$

My question, is there a simpler or more straightforward way of proving this?

Comment: Do you know complex numbers?

Comment: That was stupid of me. I think I just got it. Yes I do know complex numbers but I think I forgot what kind of question I was doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In $\mathbf C$, the roots of $x^5-1$ are the fifth roots of unity: $\;\Bigl\{\mathrm e^{\tfrac{2\mathrm ik\pi}5}\mid k=0,1,\dots 4\Bigr\}$. The complex ones are pairwise conjugates: $\;\mathrm e^{\tfrac{2\mathrm i\pi}5}$ and $\mathrm e^{\tfrac{8\mathrm i\pi}5}=\mathrm e^{-\tfrac{2\mathrm i\pi}5}$, $\;\mathrm e^{\tfrac{4\mathrm i\pi}5}$ and $\;\mathrm e^{\tfrac{6\mathrm i\pi}5}=\mathrm e^{-\tfrac{4\mathrm i\pi}5}$.

Now $(z-u)(z-\bar u)=z^2-2\operatorname{Re}(u)z+1$, knowing $\;u\bar u=1$, whence the factorisation.

One more detail: $\;\cos \dfrac{4\pi}5=-\cos\Bigl(\pi- \dfrac{4\pi}5\Bigr)=-\cos\dfrac\pi5$.

Answer (score 5):

let  $z=e^{i \theta } $

the roots of the polynomial are the fifth roots of unity.

$$ z^5-1 = (z-1)(z-e^{i \frac{2 \pi}{5}}) (z-e^{i \frac{4 \pi}{5}}) (z-e^{i \frac{6 \pi}{5}}) (z-e^{i \frac{8 \pi}{5}}) $$

$$ = (z-1)(z-e^{i \frac{2 \pi}{5}}) (z-e^{i \frac{4 \pi}{5}}) (z-e^{-i \frac{4 \pi}{5}}) (z-e^{-i \frac{2 \pi}{5}}) $$

$$ = (z-1)(z-e^{i \frac{2 \pi}{5}})(z-e^{-i \frac{2 \pi}{5}}) (z+e^{i \frac{ \pi}{5}}) (z+e^{-i \frac{ \pi}{5}}) $$

$$ = (z-1)(z^2-z(e^{i \frac{2 \pi}{5}}+ e^{-i \frac{2 \pi}{5}})+1 ) (z^2+z(e^{i \frac{ \pi}{5}}+e^{-i \frac{ \pi}{5}}) +1 ) $$

Answer (score 1):

Hint : You can use the $5^{th}$ roots of unity.

Comment: Yes I realize that now haha ..

Answer (score 0):

Use the fifth roots of unit concept it will be easier in that way as you will know the roots and hence can evaluate sum and products of the roots easily.

Answer (score 0):

You need to factor $z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1$; rewrite it as
$$
z^2\left(z^2+\frac{1}{z^2}+z+\frac{1}{z}+1\right)=
z^2\left(\left(z+\frac{1}{z}\right)^{\!2}+\left(z+\frac{1}{z}\right)-1\right)
$$
Now we can factor
$$
t^2+t-1=\left(t+\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}\right)\left(t-\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}\right)
$$
Set, guided by the text of the exercise,
$$
a=\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{4},
\qquad
b=\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{4}=a-\frac{1}{2}
$$
By substituting $t=z+1/z$, you get
$$
z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1=(z^2+2az+1)(z^2-2bz+1)
$$
Now note that
$$
2a^2-1=2\frac{5+2\sqrt{5}+1}{16}-1=\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{4}=b
$$
Similarly,
$$
2b^2-1=2\frac{5-2\sqrt{5}+1}{16}-1=-\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{4}=-a
$$
If $a=\cos\alpha$ and $b=\cos\beta$, with $0<\alpha<\pi/2$ and $0<\beta<\pi/2$, we have proved that
$$
\cos2\alpha=\cos\beta,
\qquad
\cos2\beta=-\cos\alpha
$$
Note that this implies $0<\alpha<\pi/4$, or $\cos2\alpha$ would be negative; similarly, $\pi/4<\beta<\pi/2$. Therefore $\beta=2\alpha$ and $2\beta=\pi-\alpha$, from which $\alpha=\pi/5$ and $\beta=2\pi/5$.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you want to solve this question in a quicker method, mostly using mental math and picturisation, I'd recommend keeping the circle diagram in mind. In the Argand plane, the 5 roots of unity are at equally spaced points on the circle of radius $1$, and start at $(1,0)$.
Going anticlockwise, the points are $1$, $α$, $α^2$, $α^3$ and $α^4$.
Using basic vectors, we can prove that

$α^2+α^3=-2cos(π/5)$.

Similarly,

$α+α^4=2cos(2π/5)$.

Now you can disintegrte the quadratic equations given to give;

$RHS=(z-1)(z-α)(z-α^2)(z-α^3)(z-α^4)$

Hence proved.

You can check this image for the mind-image I referred to, for more clarity. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity#/media/File:One5Root.svg