# Factorize $z^5 - 1$ using $\cos$ function

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers

This is a problem from an exam, with which I am struggling for over a month, and trying over and over. I've given up... The problem states (and my exam is tomorrow where I could expect even same problem):

$(a)$ Prove that: $$z^5 - 1 =  (z-1)(z^2 +2z\cos(\frac{\pi}5) + 1)(z^2 - 2z\cos(\frac{2\pi}5) + 1)$$
$(b)$ Find the values for $\cos\frac{\pi}5$ and $\cos\frac{2\pi}5$.

I've managed to prove $(b)$ using $(a)$, and to find all roots for the polynomial $z^5 - 1$. Also, I've managed to prove $(b)$ using "double angle formula" and then use it for $(a)$. However, I cannot prove it in the stated order (I hope it is possible).

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1422555

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complex roots of $z^5-1$ are the fifth roots of unity $\exp(2\pi i k/5)$. Thus
$$z^5-1=(z-\exp(4\pi i/5))(z-\exp(2\pi i/5))(z-1)(z-\exp(-2\pi i/5))(z-\exp(-4\pi i/5)).$$
Now use
$$(z-\exp(it))(z-\exp(-it))=z^2-(\exp(it)+\exp(-it))z+1
=z^2-2(\cos t)z+1.$$